# No power at bathroom outlets

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures, afci

Recently moved into a new house. First thing I did was go to the panel and, tediously, went through each breaker to make a detailed master breaker list. After doing so I noticed that my outside receptacle and bathrooms (2 full, 2 half) receptacles were not GFCI protected (all on the same circuit). Went and got an AFCI breaker (15A) and replaced the common breaker at the panel. A couple days ago I noticed I had lost power to these outlets. Checked the breaker and it wasn’t tripped. Reset it anyways. I get 120 at the breaker but nowhere else in the circuit. I don’t know which receptacle is the first in line (I have an educated guess that first in line is basement half bath, then main floor half bath, after it’s either guest full and master full, then last is outside receptacle. Purely based on number of lines coming in and out of each receptacle). I tried to test for continuity from panel to receptacles but I’m not getting anything. Was wondering if anyone had some additional advice/troubleshooting or if I should write it off as bad wiring from panel to first receptacle?

---

Ok, replaced AFCI with old breaker, still no power at outlets. I’m chasing down continuity to see the wiring path and I ran into a block. My guest bathroom has two sets of wires (no continuity to anything I can find) and my downstairs bathroom has two sets (one set traced to main floor bathroom) I uploaded a picture of my wire chasing (extremely simplistic. Br=breaker, Bb=basement bathroom, MB=Main floor bathroom, MsB=Master bath, GB=Guest bath, FO=Front outside, BO=Back outside).

I’ve come to the conclusion that I’ve lost two receptacles, or the wiring from breaker to guest and from guest to downstairs is fried and needs replaced. Any suggestions from the community?

[image: sketch]

Comment: Have you looked for a tripped gfci in a completely non-obvious location? I've seen bathrooms fed from garage outlets...

Comment: Are you inspecting the wires where they attach to switches, receptacles and wirenuts?

Comment: Did you try replacing the original breaker to see if everything goes back to working? You might have a bad breaker.

Comment: So I’ve inspected the wiring connecting the receptacles. I reset the sump pump GFCI, even though I know it’s on a different circuit. I’ll take a look at the others, but this house doesn’t have a lot of them. I had to say something to get a GFCI installed on the washer circuit. I’ve had this AFCI breaker installed since we moved in and had no problem for the last 6 moths. Even pulled it and tested it to ensure it wasn’t faulty.

Comment: So the AFCI breaker worked for 6-months before it started having the issues you described in your questions.  Have you tried what Barry suggestion of replacing the AFCI breaker with the standard breaker?